# Как получить экземпляр java.util.Map.Entry?

Tags: java

Как получить экземпляр java.util.Map.Entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map.Entry - интерфейс. Создать его объект нельзя. Вы можете создавать объекты классов, но не интерфейсов. При этом никто не мешает определить интерфейс - создав свой класс, а после этого, пользоваться объектами класса с помощью интерфейса.

Answer (score 3):

Получить экземпляр интерфейса нельзя. Или вам нужно вот это?:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: в дополнение можно добавить следующее:
Каждый элемент ассоциативного массива, описываемого интерфейсом Map, имеет интерфейсный тип Map.Entry, который предоставляет три основных метода:

getKey() — возвращает ключ элемента;

getValue() — возвращает значение элемента;

setValue(Object value) — меняет значение элемента.

Метод entrySet(), определенный в интерфейсе Map, позволят получить все элементы ассоциативного массива в виде множества объектов типа Map.Entry.

Answer (score 1):

невозможное становится возможным иногда:

```
    java.util.Map.Entry < String, String > s = new java.util.Map.Entry < String, String > ()
    {

        @Override
        public String getKey ()
        {
            return null ;
        }

        @Override
        public String getValue ()
        {
            return null ;
        }

        @Override
        public String setValue ( String value )
        {
            return null ;
        }
    };
```

внимание вопрос, - а зачем вам это? в данном виде код выглядит не лучшим образом, в большинстве случаев лучше сделать свой класс который имплементирует этот интерфейс.

Comment: Я так и поступил.

Comment: правильно поступили. хотя по большему счету, этот пример, это не создание экземпляра интерфейса, а создание экземпляра безимянного абстрактного класса, который наследует нужный вам интерфейс :)

Comment: @jmu Опять же нет. Это создание объекта от нового анонимного класса ( полноценного класса, у которого отсутствует свой интерфейс доступа ) с указанным интерфейсом. От абстрактных классов нельзя создавать объекты.

Answer (score 1):

1. AbstractMap.SimpleEntry entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(1, 2);
2. JDK 9: Map.entry(1,2);